# PHP mail sending doesn't works with this ajax code but works fine without ajax code, with echo in my php.I want response in same page

Tags: php, ajax

My HTML code. Here above the form I want to show the response like Email is sending, and after that Thankyou message.

```
<form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Name"</div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email Id"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Your text here"></textarea></div>                        
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-submit" value="Submit"></div>
</form>
```

My PHP code. When I am using echo and without the ajax its working fine. But The response is coming in sendmail.php page. I want ajax response above the form in html page..

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "sample@gmail.com"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $subject = "Form submission";
    $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
    $message = $name. " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
    // echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $name . ", we will contact you shortly.";

    die();
    }
?>
```

My Ajax code

```
var form = $('#main-contact-form');
    form.submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            beforeSend: function(){
                form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn() );
            }
        }).done(function(data){
            form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact you</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
        });
    });
```

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: Hi, @jayblanchard Its showing all ajax response, But not sending mail..Without Ajax code it sends mail correctly..yes I have tested on server.

Comment: Have you checked te error logs?

Comment: I can't check error log. I am new :) I am a front end developer but I need this mail sending feature in a site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't send any data to the server and will perform a `GET` request, so your `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` will always return false when an AJAX request is made. You need to update your JavaScript so the form data is serialised:

```
var form = $('#main-contact-form');

form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        method: 'post',
        beforeSend: function(){
            form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn() );
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact you</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

You could improve your PHP too, by changing the `if` to something like this so it just detects the post request:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you @edcs its working just superb!! Thank you so much for this rapid fix.